# Matlab - How to scan a text document for specific data, then report a line number

Tags: matlab

I would like to scan a text file, containing data such as shown below, for a specific phrase and then print out the line number where this phrase occurs. For example: If I want to find where the phrase `G01 Z0. F5.` occurs, the solution would be "line 5." I have experimented with using `textscan` and `fscanf`, but I have not been able to find a working solution. Any and all help is appreciated.

Sample text file:

```
G17 G20 G90 G94 G54
G0 Z0.25
X-0.5 Y0.
Z0.1
G01 Z0. F5.
G02 X0. Y0.5 I0.5 J0. F2.5
X0.5 Y0. I0. J-0.5
X0. Y-0.5 I-0.5 J0.
X-0.5 Y0. I0. J0.5
G01 Z0.1 F5.
G00 X0. Y0. Z0.25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
% Read all the lines in the text file...
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
input = textscan(fid,'%[^\n]'); 
data = input{1,1};
fclose(fid);

% Define the target string...
target = 'G01 Z0. F5.';

% Fine the lines that contain the target string...
k = find(contains(data,target)) % Output: 5
```

The [contains function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html) acts in such way that every string that **contains** the target string is matched. This means that if your text file content was:

```
G17 G20 G90 G94 G54
G0 Z0.25
X-0.5 Y0.
Z0.1
abc G01 Z0. F5. abc
G02 X0. Y0.5 I0.5 J0. F2.5
X0.5 Y0. I0. J-0.5
X0. Y-0.5 I-0.5 J0.
X-0.5 Y0. I0. J0.5
G01 Z0.1 F5.
G00 X0. Y0. Z0.25
```

the index `5` would be returned anyway. If you want to restrict your search to exact matches, use the following code with [strcmp](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) instead:

```
% Read all the lines in the text file...
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
input = textscan(fid,'%[^\n]'); 
data = input{1,1};
fclose(fid);

% Define the target string...
target = 'G01 Z0. F5.';

% Fine the lines that contain the target string...
k = find(strcmp(data,target)) % Output: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works, uses textdata to read in each line into one cell (ie with Delimiter='' to avoid splitting with whitespace), and then searches for the first occurrence of the text

```
str_to_find='G01 Z0. F5.'    

fileID=fopen('sample.txt');
textdata=textscan(fileID,'%s','Delimiter','');
fclose(fileID);

for p =1:size(textdata{1},1)
    if strfind(textdata{1}{p},str_to_find)            
        fprintf('line %d',p);
        break;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function L = scantxt(filename,check)
fid = fopen(filename,'rt');
l = fgetl(fid);ct=1;
L = -1;
while ~isnumeric(l)
    if strcmp(l,check),L=ct;fclose(fid);return;end
    l=fgetl(fid);ct=ct+1;
end
fclose(fid);
```

Result:

```
>> check = 'G01 Z0. F5.';
>> scantxt('test.txt',check)

ans =

     5
```